# Differentiability of $\Psi(x) = \frac{1}{\phi(x)}$, $\phi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

How to infer the differentiability of

$$\Psi(x) = \frac{1}{\phi(x)}$$

where $\phi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Can this be done with the one-dimensional definition of derivative, i.e.

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

since $\phi (x) \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta: t \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\} \mapsto \frac1t$. Then $\psi = \theta \circ \phi$, and provided $\phi$ is never zero, i.e. that $\phi(G) \subset \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, we get that $\theta$ is differentiable on $\phi(G)$, hence $\psi$ is differentiable on $G$ and by chain rule,

$$D \psi(x) = \theta'(\phi(x)) D \phi(x) = -\frac1{(\phi(x))^2} D \phi(x)$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you get that $\theta$ is differentiable?

Comment: @mavavilj well $\theta$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, so it is differentiable on any set contained in $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ (in particular on $\phi(G)$)

Comment: My notes don't use the gradient. Is $\nabla \Psi(x) = D \Psi(x)$? Or is it equal to $D \Psi(x) \cdot u$?

Comment: @mavavilj rather, it is the transpose. I'll edit the answer.